# How to get the Google Maps to work on the iPad via the web browser?

Tags: ipad, google-maps

I have created a webapplication which uses a google map, but when I view the website on the ipad web browser it does not let me select the markers? Is there some MarkerOption I have to set to enable Google Map markers to be selected on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { ... }
```

If so, try 'mouseup' instead of 'click'.

Comment: Great.  Please don't forget to assign the bounty :)